# Title for Keyboard Shortcut in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I want to change the discoverability title of a keyboard shortcut in SwiftUI.
As you can see below the title shows in the popup if used in text button, but if you use an image for the button it doesn't show in the popup (when holding cmd on the keyboard to view supported shortcuts by the app).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Button("Save to Favorites") {

            }
            .keyboardShortcut("a")

            Button {

            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            }
            .keyboardShortcut("s")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

How can I add a title to the shortcuts help popup?

Note that I have tried all accessibility stuff, i.e. label, identifier, hint, etc... and It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Not a super elegant solution but I got it working by adding a `Text` with a `.frame` size of `width: 0, height: 0`. This effectively hides the `Text` from view but ensures it appears when the user holds down the ⌘ key.

Consider putting it in a `ZStack` too as the default arrangement could have it ever so slightly off centre.

```swift
VStack {
    Button("Save to Favorites") {
        
    }
    .keyboardShortcut("a")
    
    Button {
        
    } label: {
        ZStack {
            Text("heart")
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0) // <- this part
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
        }
    }
    .keyboardShortcut("s")
}
```

[image: Command Key held down]

Comment: How to remove or change the title "test"?

Comment: "test" in this case is the app's name